# Spring: Default or no-arg constructor is missing in @Configuration

Tags: spring, configuration, constructor

I am preparing for a Spring core exam and on one of the mock questions I am getting a very confusing answer.

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public ApplicationConfig(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }
    @Bean(name="clientRepository")
    ClientRepository jpaClientRepository() {
        return new JpaClientRepository();
    }
}
```

The answer states: Default or no-arg constructor is missing. Default or no-arg constructor is mandatory. Here, the provided constructor with a dataSource parameter is not taken into account.

I don't understand first why constructor is required and second why ApplicationConfig is no good.

Answer (score 1):

`@Configuration` specifically is an odd beast. Spring needs to analyze it to build a dependency graph before it has the beans to supply, so you can't use constructor injection with a configuration class.

Answer (score 0):

The reason will be clear if you try to register the above configuration with an application context, e.g.:

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext = 
            new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ApplicationConfig.class);
```

The framework will throw an exception complaining about the missing default constructor, because it will look for it while trying to instantiate the configuration using reflection.

A better way would be to have @Autowired dataSource field:

```
@Autowired DataSource dataSource;
```

and no constructor explicitely defined (i.e. having an implicit default no-arg constructor).